# Move and rotate an object according to travel distance and direction between objects

Tags: python, object-mode

I need to rotate the target object an equivalent distance to the distance between two objects in the direction of the travel distance between them.

[image]

I've tried to subtract them and get the `rotation_difference` between the subtraction result and a zero rotation axis `mathutils.Quaternion()` but the result is different from what I need.

```
import bpy
import mathutils

selected_object = bpy.context.object
car_f1_location = bpy.data.objects['car_f1'].location.copy()
car_f2_location = bpy.data.objects['car_f2'].location.copy()

direction_vec = car_f2_location - car_f1_location
direction = direction_vec.rotation_difference( mathutils.Quaternion() )

selected_object.rotation_quaternion = direction
```

But the resulting rotation is different from what I want.

Comment: Nice use of grease pencil in the screenshots :)

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that I needed to use `to_track_quat()` instead of `rotation_difference()` to get the direction along this vector.

```
import bpy
import mathutils

selected_object = bpy.context.object
car_f1_location = bpy.data.objects['car_f1'].location.copy()
car_f2_location = bpy.data.objects['car_f2'].location.copy()

direction_vec = car_f2_location - car_f1_location
direction = direction_vec.to_track_quat('Y', 'Z')

selected_object.rotation_quaternion = direction
```